# How to refresh jsp page when context attribute is added or replaced only?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am making one demo web Application in which I am stuck in between of some logic and implementation. Scenario is as follows:

One page is there for Order(Customer)  and  another page is for Kitchen(chef).

I want some functionality:

- whenever Customer Place an Order than and than Kitchen(chef) should
  refresh the page.

For that I have put all detail of Customer's Order in **Context Attribute** and

- Listener class for **ServletContextAttributeListener** I have
  implemented in which I am setting **flag to value 1** for new Context
  Attribute Added or Replaced.

In Kitchen(chef)'s JSP page, 
I want to check **continuously** whether the Flag is set or not in infinite loop and also want process the code written in JSP page.

Can it be achieved by thread and Joining of thread? Or there are other ways to do it?
Can anyone help for this?

Comment: A JSP is executed at server-side. Once the JSP is executed, the browser just has an HTML page, and you may change all you want at server-side, the HTML page won't refresh. You need some kind of auto-refresh or AJAX polling at client-side, or use comet to push changes, but it's more complex than what you imagine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ajax polling that will check continuously and if there is any change you can do action using javascript